# mysql_fetch_array, not valid - combining tables in one php page

Tags: php, mysql, join

i've got the following code

```
$data = mysql_query(
"SELECT md.*, qr.* 
FROM moduleDetails md 
LEFT JOIN qResponses qr 
ON qr.userno = md.userno");

print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
        { 
            print "<tr>"; 
            print "<th>Faculty</th> <td>".$info['faculty'] . "</td>"; 
            print "<th>Module Code</th> <td>".$info['moduleCode'] . "</td>"; 
            print "<th>Date Started</th> <td>".$info['dateStarted'] . "</td>"; 
            print "<th>Module Title</th> <td>".$info['moduleTitle'] . "</td>"; 
            print "<th>School</th> <td>".$info['school'] . "</td></tr>"; 

        } 
        print "</table>";
```

it's giving me a error on line 31, which is the $info = mysql_fetch.... etc

What have i done wrong?.. i can't see a fix for this, it wasnt working fine before before i involved two tables.. any help would be great - cant see whats wrong - new to joining tables.

Comment: can you post the line before $data = mysql_query(...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you get no results from the query. Execute the query to verify it gives result and check you have results before trying to fetch them

```
if (mysql_num_rows($data) == 0)
       die("No Records");
      elseif (mysql_num_rows($data) > 0)
      {
       while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
         {
                ...............
         }
       }
      else { die("Something else went wrong"); }
```

Or even better wrap it in a try/catch